# Attempt to invoke a virtual method on a ImageView, which seems to be null

Tags: java, android

I'm getting this error now with this file but I've using the same approach from the beginning, it used to work perfectly. I need assistance with this.

This is the error : *Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ImageView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference *

I get for the ImageView

I'm creating a Splash Screen for the app

**Below is the .java file for the activity**

```
package com.anurag.college_information;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView SplashImg;
    TextView SplashText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        SplashImg.findViewById(R.id.iv_splash);
        SplashText.findViewById(R.id.tv_splash);

        SplashImg.animate().translationY(-1600).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(1000);
        SplashText.animate().translationY(1600).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(1000);



        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, 3000);

    }
}
```

**This is the .xml file for the activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#7CB342"
    tools:context=".SplashScreenActivity">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_splash"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/graduation_hat" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_splash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="@font/toon"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:shadowColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_below="@id/iv_splash"
            android:shadowDx="12"
            android:shadowDy="10"
            android:shadowRadius="40"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="College Info"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="63sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Error msg**

[image: Screenshot of the logcat window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify here:

```
SplashImg.findViewById(R.id.iv_splash);
SplashText.findViewById(R.id.tv_splash);
```

to such:

```
SplashImg = findViewById(R.id.iv_splash);
SplashText = findViewById(R.id.tv_splash);
```

The error means you need assign these variables before using (invoking any methods on) them.